# Crack on Carbon Frame?

Tags: crack

I see a crack on the carbon frame of my bike

https://www.dropbox.com/s/flqrue2plzyqki9/DSC_0118.JPG?dl=0

[image]

The bike is around 4 years old but I just notice the crack line now.  I think there was always some kind of a hairline crack just a few months after getting it.  Its about 3/4 away around, but is it paint or more serious ? the picture is not the best.

What are my options going forward ? do you start to look at a replacement frame, send it to be fixed  ? (its a Cannondale Super Six 105 Carbon 2012)

Answer (score 2):

According to Cannondales website they offer limited lifetime warranties on their frames. They also have a passage that states"The specific warranty covering your Cannondale bicycle is governed by the law of the state or country in which it was purchased, and applies only to bicycles purchased from Authorized Cannondale Retailers". That said my first stop would be the dealer that you bought it from. I would stop riding it until they check it out. You don't want a warranty denial due to the fact you rode it damaged. If you get an unsatisfactory response I would seek a second opinion from a shop that specializes in carbon frame repair. I believe most shops don't see enough frames to form a valid opinion. Or they fear litigation (rightfully so) and make a judgment for safety sake.  You may save a few coins if you disassemble the bottom bracket so they can get a look inside the shell. 
  I had a Cervelo R3 with a similar looking flaw. After having it checked by a shop (Hot Tubes) that does custom builds and frame repairs. They determined it was stress cracks in the paint. That was several years ago and it has not gotten worse.

---

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I got the bike from the U.K, I live in the Republic of Ireland so I'm not sure if there is any warranty.  Plus I assembled the bike myself from its box, I think this voids any warranty?  Im going to bring it to the LBS in the next few days for a second opinion but I just got the bike back today after them fixing the bottom bracket